# Excel VBA & MS A Query if Null Then increase variable

Tags: excel, vba, sql, null

Estoy realizando una macro donde obtengo el valor de una celda y lo incremento ya que es mi referencia de Búsqueda pero cuando no existe el registro que tengo agregado se vuelve cíclico y no puedo salir, Quiero que en caso de no tener la base datos el registro incremente la variable hasta no tener ningún resultao de la variable buscada. envío mi código para que por favor me apoyen.

Saludos,

```
Sub ObtenerStatus()

    'Varaibles
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim datos As Object
    Dim consultaSQL As String
    Dim Conexion As String
    Dim cont As Long
    Dim Row1 As Long
    Dim NRequi As String


        cont = 3
        Row1 = 3
        NRequi = Cells(Row1, 1)

'Conectar a la Base de datos
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    'Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            Conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;" & _
                        "Data Source = W:\Compras 2\Compras 2019.accdb"
        cn.Open Conexion

While Not NRequi = " "

        NRequi = Cells(Row1, 1)

    'consulta
      consultaSQL = "SELECT * FROM Requisici?n WHERE [N?mero de Requisici?n] = " & "'" & NRequi & "'"

       Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSQL)

    If datos = Nothing Then
        Row1 = Row1 + 2
        cont = cont + 2
    Else
        Do While Not datos.EOF
                Cells(cont, 10) = datos.Fields("Estatus")
                Cells(cont, 11) = datos.Fields("Fecha Estimada de Entrega")
                Cells(cont, 12) = datos.Fields("Observaciones")
                cont = cont + 1
                Row1 = Row1 + 1
                datos.MoveNext
        Loop
            datos.Close
            Set datos = Nothing
    End If
Wend
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa `NRequi = " "`? Si lo que quieres es que el Loop se detenga cuando Nrequi esté vacío, deberías usar `NRequi = ""` en vez de un espacio en blanco. Si no, te recorrerá todas las celdas de toda la columna hasta la dfila un millón

Comment: Gracias por el dato, solo me falta saber como hacer que me devuelva un valor para así poder realizar una condicional

Comment: No entiendo cuando dices *como hacer que me devuelva un valor*. ¿Quien quieres que te devuelva el valor? ¿El Recordse? ¿De dónde lo quieres sacar?

Comment: Buenas tardes soy novato en cuanto programación en VBA, no se si el recordset me puede devolver un valor en caso de que la "consultaSQL" no se encuentre o no tenga valor. para así incrementar mi varible de NRequi y no se cicle.

Comment: saludos y gracias por tu apoyo

Comment: Te lo tendrías que configurar tú con un IF. Me explico: Tú te haces una petición en SQL, y la ejecutas mediante un recordset. Si tu petición en SQL no devuelve nada, devuelve un Recordset de 0 registros. Es decir, en tu caso, sería algo como `If Datos.Eof=True And Datos.BOF=True then...`. Si EOF y BOF son True, es que tu consulta no tiene valor, y podrías controlar con un IF lo que quieres que el código haga. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Otra sugerencia, si quieres traer TODOS los registros con TODOS los campos que has metido en tu consulta SQL, echa un vistazo a [Método Range.CopyFromRecordset (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.CopyFromRecordset). Es la manera más rápida de volcar a Excel todos los datos de un objeto Recordset :)

Comment: @Orlando he notado lo siguiente en el código posteado. Supongamos que estás efectuado el bucle de `A1:A10` y que todas estás celdas contienen datos, cuando sea el turno de `A11` la variable será `NRequi = ""`, por tanto como no hay una condición que rompá el bucle `While`, se ejecutará la `consultaSQL` lo cual ya no es necesario. Entonces tendrías que colocar antes de **consultaSQL** lo siguiente: `if (NRequi = "") then Exit do` para que esto no suceda

Comment: O en su defecto si ya has definido fuera del bucle `While` la variable `NRequi` -línea 15 del código- escribir  `NRequi = Cells(Row1, 1)` al final de todo el bucle `While`

Comment: Buenas tardes, Muchas Gracias a todos, @ElierSánchezE-Infantes, me ayudo mucho tu apoyo con eso pude controlar el incrementar mis variables

Comment: como también @Hubert Roland me apoyo mucho el poder controlar mi ciclo While, envío como quedó el código

Comment: Ya no me deja ingresar todo el código pero si lo requieren por favor manden inbox